# How to: calculate percentile values for each values in R

Tags: r, percentile

I need to calculate percentile ranks for all the values in four columns in a dataset. The result should be something like this:

```
Name   Value1   Percentile1   Value2  Percentile2  Value3  Percentile3  Value4  Percentile4
 a       X        0.000000               ....            ....            ....
 b       X        0.159272               ....            ....            ....
 c       X        1.000000               ....            ....            ....
 d       X        0.240728               ....            ....            ....
...
```

The format of each percentile is 6-decimal. Could anyone please help with this?
I tried ntile() but it can't give me 6 decimal numbers.

Comment: Without a reproducible data set, it's difficult to get a proper answer. That said, take a look at `dplyr::across`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's first generate some data

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
df <- tibble(
name = letters, 
value1 = rnorm(length(letters)),
value2 = -rnorm(length(letters)),
value3 = abs(rnorm(length(letters))) )
```

Function for calculating percentile ranks (source: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/11928)

```
perc.rank <- function(x) trunc(rank(x))/length(x)


df %>% mutate(
percentile1 = perc.rank(value1),
percentile2 = perc.rank(value2),
percentile3 = perc.rank(value3)
) -> df


> df

   name  value1  value2 value3 percentile1 percentile2 percentile3
   <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 a     -0.626  0.156  0.341        0.192      0.615        0.308
 2 b      0.184  1.47   1.13         0.462      1            0.731
 3 c     -0.836  0.478  1.43         0.115      0.808        0.808
 4 d      1.60  -0.418  1.98         1          0.308        0.923
```

Comment: It works and it is exactly the result I want! Thank you Otto!